# How For loop result concat by column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe , I split data into 3 segments, applied for loop and calculate features of data, I want to join the result of 3 loops in one row and change column name by adding 1,2,3 at the end of the feature column name.

```
splitt=np.array_split(df,3)
for x in splitt:
    x1=np.mean(A)
    x1=pd.DataFrame([x1],columns=['mean'])
    x1['std']=np.std
```

desired_result;

```
    mean_A_1 std_B_1  mean_A_2 std_B_2  mean_A_3 std_B_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,5,5,8,9,6],'B':[5,8,0,9,5,6,3]})

splitt=np.array_split(df,3)
L = {k: v for i, x in enumerate(splitt, 1) 
          for k, v in {f'mean_A_{i}': x['A'].mean(), f'std_B_{i}': np.std(x['B'])}.items()}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([L])
print (df1)
   mean_A_1   std_B_1  mean_A_2  std_B_2  mean_A_3  std_B_3
0       2.0  3.299832       6.5      2.0       7.5      1.5
```

Another solution with loop:

```
L = []
splitt=np.array_split(df,3)
for i, x in enumerate(splitt, 1):
    d = {f'mean_A_{i}': x['A'].mean(), 
         f'std_B_{i}': np.std(x['B'])}
    L.append(pd.Series(d))


df1 = pd.concat(L).to_frame().T
print (df1)
   mean_A_1   std_B_1  mean_A_2  std_B_2  mean_A_3  std_B_3
0       2.0  3.299832       6.5      2.0       7.5      1.5
```

Comment: i need to apply some other function , i need to use simple for loop to do this task , for example each segment FFT calcuation and then select frequency range and then same largest frequency in result dataframe , with this method i think its not possible

Comment: @Edward - I edit answer, only add your code for `d` dictionary.